# How to select the text of respective table data separately under table row with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

This is the code

```
<tbody id="table-body">

 <tr>
      <td id="c1">AAA0</td>
      <td id="c2">2%</td>

 </tr>

</tbody>
```

I want to select data of ID c1 under < tr > tag. 
I am using this jQuery code but it is selecting whole text under < tr > tag.

```
$("#table-body").on('click','tr',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log($(this).text());
})
```

I am getting **AAA02%** as the output if this code.
I want to select **AAA0** and **2** separately. 
How to do it ?

Comment: IDs are unique, why not just use id to select?

Answer (score 3):

Since there is more than one *td* element in each clicked *tr* element, you have to loop through each of them to get the text individually.

You can use `find()` and `each()` like the following way:

```js
$("#table-body").on('click','tr',function(e){
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td id="c1">AAA0</td>
      <td id="c2">2%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
console.log($(this).find('.c1').text());
```

And use class attribute instead of id

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all text inside `tr` because you are binding `click` event on the `tr` and so `$(this)` refers to the`tr` you clicked.

To get **AAA0** only, you can use `children()` and pass `id` to select a specific `td`

```
$("#table-body").on('click','tr',function(e){
    console.log($(this).children('#c1').text());
});
```

But since you are assinginig `id` to the `td`'s, you can also directly attach the `click` event to the `td` as

```
$("#table-body #c1").on('click','tr',function(e){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```